# How to map this oboject to only get messages which is 'text' in this object

Tags: python, api

The object i got from telegram api is like this:

```
{
    'ok': True,
    'result': [
    {
        'update_id': 633425135,
        'message':
        {
            'message_id': 2,
            'from':
            {
                'id': 5060166011,
                'is_bot': False,
                'first_name': 'Mosquito',
                'username': 'TheMosquitoo',
                'language_code': 'en'
            },
            'chat':
            {
                'id': 5060166011,
                'first_name': 'Mosquito',
                'username': 'TheMosquitoo',
                'type': 'private'
            },
            'date': 1641723768,
            'text': 'asdfasdf'
        }
    },
    {
        'update_id': 633425136,
        'message':
        {
            'message_id': 4,
            'from':
            {
                'id': 874434712,
                'is_bot': False,
                'first_name': '1DS18TE030',
                'username': 'thekumaraswamy',
                'language_code': 'en'
            },
            'chat':
            {
                'id': 874434712,
                'first_name': '1DS18TE030',
                'username': 'thekumaraswamy',
                'type': 'private'
            },
            'date': 1641723894,
            'text': '/start',
            'entities': [
            {
                'offset': 0,
                'length': 6,
                'type': 'bot_command'
            }]
        }
    },
    {
        'update_id': 633425137,
        'message':
        {
            'message_id': 5,
            'from':
            {
                'id': 874434712,
                'is_bot': False,
                'first_name': '1DS18TE030',
                'username': 'thekumaraswamy',
                'language_code': 'en'
            },
            'chat':
            {
                'id': 874434712,
                'first_name': '1DS18TE030',
                'username': 'thekumaraswamy',
                'type': 'private'
            },
            'date': 1641723910,
            'text': ''
        }
    },
    {
        'update_id': 633425138,
        'message':
        {
            'message_id': 7,
            'from':
            {
                'id': 874434712,
                'is_bot': False,
                'first_name': '1DS18TE030',
                'username': 'thekumaraswamy',
                'language_code': 'en'
            },
            'chat':
            {
                'id': 874434712,
                'first_name': '1DS18TE030',
                'username': 'thekumaraswamy',
                'type': 'private'
            },
            'date': 1641723957,
            'text': '*kumaraswamy'
        }
    }]
}
```

i wanted to map this object such that i only get messages, first_name and last_name...
please help me.

Comment: I also need username to be mapped.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (`obj` is your object, i.e. the object returned by the API call):

```
result = [
    {'message_text': msg['message']['text'],
     'username': msg['message']['from']['username'],
     'first_name': msg['message']['from']['first_name']}
    for msg in obj['result']]
```

This is the result:

```
[
    {
        'message_text': 'asdfasdf',
        'username': 'TheMosquitoo',
        'first_name': 'Mosquito',
    },
    {
        'message_text': '/start',
        'username': 'thekumaraswamy',
        'first_name': '1DS18TE030',
    },
    {
        'message_text': '',
        'username': 'thekumaraswamy',
        'first_name': '1DS18TE030',
    },
    {
        'message_text': '*kumaraswamy',
        'username': 'thekumaraswamy',
        'first_name': '1DS18TE030',
    },
]
```